# Django Model conditional relationship

Tags: django, django-models, postgis, geodjango

Newbie question: Django + Postgres + PostGIS

I am trying to setup a Projects model in Django that needs to be conditionally related to a geometry model depending on its geometry type. the geometry types are : Points, Lines or Polygons. The question is how do I define this relationship in the Project Model so that I do not have to save the different geometry types in the same table ( Hence the 3 different geometry models)

=======================Here are my models ============================

```
PRJ_GEOM = (
         (1, "point"),
         (2, "line"),
         (3, "polygon")
  )

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    project_geom_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PRJ_GEOM)
    project_geometry = models.OneToOneField( ????) # I am stuck here - how do I express this conditional relationship which depends on project_geom_type
```

# Geometry Model

```
class Project_Point_Geom(models.Model):
      project = models.OneToOne(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_point')
      point = models.PointField()

class Project_Line_Geom(models.Model):
      project = models.OneToOne(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_line')
      line = models.LineStringField()

class Project_Polygon_Geom(models.Model):
      project = models.OneToOne(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_polygon')
      polygon = models.PolygonField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you only need one model. All geometry fields are derived from [GeometryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geometryfield) so you can use it to store it's sub classes.

```
PRJ_GEOM = (
         (1, "point"),
         (2, "line"),
         (3, "polygon")
  )

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    project_geom_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PRJ_GEOM)
    project_geometry = models.GeometryField()
```

That is all! one model, one table instead of four which is much easier to maintain. And the data is slightly smaller because the relation field is eliminated.

Comment: I am assuming that this will result in different geometry types being saved in the same field called project_geometry right. From my GIS experience I know this is not a good idea but maybe ot doesn't matter. Any clues ? Does it matter?

Comment: yeah, it doesn't matter that different geometries are saved in the same field type.

Comment: This is great. Wondering if this will have any implication on the results of a spatial query - say I am looking to query all projects within a polygon - I know point geoms will return a collection, for lines and polygons how will that result look like? Does postgis perform a intersection and returns all geometries that are within the boundary polygon?

Comment: if you are asking about the __within or __dwithin postgis queries, yes they work with any geometry types. Your project_geom_type column tells your what your type is. But even that isn't really needed because the type can be determined by inspecting the geometry field itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Project` model doesn't need the `project_geometry` fields. You only need to relate your different geometry models to the project using your `OneToOne` field. Django automatically creates reverse relationships for `ForeignKey`, `ManyToMany` and `OneToOne` relationships. Your classes would look something like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Point_Geo(models.Model):
      project = models.OneToOne(Project) # truncated for example
      point = models.PointField()

class Line_Geo(models.Model):
      project = models.OneToOne(Project) # truncated for example
      line = models.LineStringField()

class Polygon_Geo(models.Model):
      project = models.OneToOne(Project) # truncated for example
      polygon = models.PolygonField()
```

When you've got a `Project` instance you can walk back along the reverse relationship like this:

```
project = Project.objects.get(id=1)
point = project.point_geo.point
```

To query for all projects with point geometry you could query:

```
projects_with_points = Project.objects.exclude(point_geo=None)
```

Comment: Without that field how will I know the geometry type of a project? Lets say I have a project Id won't I need 3 queries in the worst case to figure out its geometry?

Comment: You could query for it by checking if any of the reverse relationships are none, but I was mostly just simplifying for the example.